# How to create gantt chart view for iPad application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, quartz-core, gantt-chart

I need to create an iPad application which has the same features like "Quickplan" iPad application (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7S3x2iYhyKw 
or http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1564227)

I have no idea from where to begin, specially when creating Gantt chart. I did research on internet but couldn't find any useful resources.

What would be the best approach? (whether it should develop from monotouch or Objective-C). Is there any third party libraries (drawing Gantt charts) to do this on Objective-C?

Comment: I don't know of any pre-existing modules that you can simply use to achieve that. In essence you have to build it from scratch. Perhaps playing around with coreplot ( http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/ ) might lead you somewhere although I doubt it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Javier! I have looked at it, but it isn't going to help!

Answer (score 1):

[IQ Widgets](https://github.com/evolvIQ/iqwidgets) has a Gantt chart.  You would need to generate bindings in order to use it in MonoTouch.

Comment: Can you please explain this little more (or share some sample code) as I new to iOS development and this is bit tough task for me! I have looked at the IQ Widgets and couldn't get better idea out of it. What would be the easiest way to develop such a feature (gantt chart)?